# In Android Studio what is the equivalent of CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE under ndk-build?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am trying to push some existing Android.mk-based native code into a new Android Studio app. There are some linking errors that give the message "Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". When using CMake, one can set the variable CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE to make this the default behavior. Is there a way to do something similar under ndk-build? Trying to run ndk-build from the command line with -v or V=1 (not sure which is best) in an Android Studio context seems awkward.

Edit:

As noted in the response below, this should be possible from Gradle using the "arguments" keyword. My interpretation of this is this version of the Module: app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adth.jwc.testproj4"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "$projectDir/jni/Android.mk"
            arguments "V=1"
       }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This generates the error message "Error:(16, 0) Could not find method ndkBuild() for arguments [build_95llvy1tc979yxena3spokoe8$_run_closure1$_closure3@34646897] on root project 'TestProj4' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

I have also tried some variations, all of which generate essentially the same error. What is the correct placement of the "arguments" keyword in the build.gradle file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [DSL reference](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/), it looks like you need to put the `exernalNativeBuild` block in a product flavor or build type block to add arguments, so

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.adth.jwc.testproj4"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments "V=1"
        }
    }
}
```

should work. Confusingly, `BaseExtension` (the `android` block) can also have an `externalNativeBuild` block, but its `ndkBuild` property is an [`NdkBuildOptions`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkBuildOptions.html) object, which only has a `path` property. The `ndkBuild` blocks for flavors and build types are [`ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions.html) objects, which have `arguments` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`ndkBuild { arguments "V=1" }` in your build.gradle, and then run gradle with `--info` (Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Command-line Options).

For command line ndk-build usage, run `ndk-build V=1`.

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#link-gradle

Comment: My interpretation of this does not seem to work. Please see the edited question above.

Comment: Updated my answer. I believe you need to run gradle with --info for it to stop suppressing the information that ndk-build is printing.

Comment: --info does in fact cause Gradle to dump a lot of information, but it does not deal with the arguments error noted above.